# Excel VBA Writing in-line VBScript - Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: excel, vba, csv, vbscript

I am trying to import CSV file into MS Excel (2016) using VBA Code. Manipulating import didn't work so far, Excel uses windows system delimiter every time over what I am trying to set in VBA import.

So, I thought to use a VBScript to change system delimiter from 'comma' to 'Tab' at first, import CSV file, then set system delimiter back to 'comma'.

Having VBScript as separate file and running it by:

```
    Shell "wscript D:\Hutsul\ChangeDelimiter.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

Works, but VBA needs to run on other machines, and for ease of use I wanted to try and code VBScript in-line within Excel VBA environment.
Code that I have written stops at `Set scr = New ScriptControl` and throws:
**Run-time Error '429': ActiveX component can't create object**

Tried `set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")` didn't help. 
Also, here is a snip of my VBAProject References:

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
- Microsoft Script Control 1.0
- Microsoft Scriptlet Library

Below is my VBA code for in-line script (Separate Script file contains just what's in `scriptCode` lines:

```
'Execute VBScript directly from VBA to change system delimiter from COMMA to TAB
Dim scriptCode As String
Dim scr As ScriptControl: Set scr = New ScriptControl
scriptCode = ""
scriptCode = scriptCode & "Set sh = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")"
scriptCode = scriptCode & "Path = ""HKCU\Control Panel\International\sList"""
scriptCode = scriptCode & "Set Separator = CreateObject(""Scripting.Dictionary"")"
scriptCode = scriptCode & "Separator.Add True, ""\t"""
scriptCode = scriptCode & "Separator.Add False, "","""
scriptCode = scriptCode & "sh.RegWrite Path, Separator(sh.RegRead(Path) = "",""), ""REG_SZ"""

scr.Language = "VBScript"
scr.AddCode scriptCode
scr.Run scriptCode
```

Also, when the script itself is executed (as a separate .vbs file for now) **multiple times**, it **switches delimiter**, instead of just setting from 'comma' to 'Tab' and keeping it that way, so if delimiter is already 'Tab' and I run script again, delimiter becomes 'comma' again.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Register `C:\Windows\System32\MSscript.ocx` and you should be ok :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout successfully registered MSscript.ocx but same error afterwards

Comment: I see what the problem is.. Let me post an answer

Comment: Why doesn't you VBS code work as is in VBA.. VBScript is designed to be pastable into VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `VBScript` on a 64-bit Windows as a 32-bit process or a 64-bit process. I believe you have a 64 bit system and hence when you double click it, it is running it as 32-bit.. resulting in error. If you are running 32-bit, then you need the 32-bit ActiveX and if running 64-bit, then you need the 64-bit ActiveX.

To run a 32-bit VBScript on a 64-bit system, try this

Create a new VBS file called `Test.Vbs` and save it at as `C:\Temp\Test.Vbs` Type these two lines in that file.

```
Set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
MsgBox "Success"
```

Now press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to launch `Run`. Type this

```
C:\windows\sysWOW64\cscript C:\Temp\test.vbs
```

Does it run now? Do you see the message box "Success"?

If the above doesn't run then try this

```
C:\windows\system32\cscript C:\Temp\test.vbs
```

One of them will run.

Comment: Running a separate file worked with command `C:\windows\sysWOW64\cscript C:\Temp\test.vbs` , running Script code in VBA still throws same error. Need to know how to force this kind of execution in VBA `Set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")`

Comment: VBA should not give you any issues. It works just fine for me. Yours is a 64 bit windows with 32 bit office?

Comment: got 64 bit system with 64 bit Office 2016. Also, have another installation of 2010 Excel and Access that are 64 bit as well. Tried on 2010 with the same results. So if VBScript is in its own file, that code `Set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")` still fails during plain run, but runs if executed with command you gave me. But, when I run script through Excel VBA (Code I provided) then if fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}]
@="ScriptControl Object"
"AppID"="{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\AppID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}]
"DllSurrogate"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}]
"DllSurrogate"=""
```

This reg file enables MSScriptControl for x64 programs by forcing MSScript's 32 bit DLLs into the 32 bit DLLHost allowing 64 bit programs to access this 32 bit dll. COM objects in exe files can be accessed by both 64 and 32 bit programs.

As Regedit requires admin permissions to start, if not an Admin use this batch file to merge the reg file as reg.exe doesn't require admin permissions to start. The registry file only contains per user settings which all users are allowed to change (but with reg.exe not regedit.exe).

```
reg import "%~dp0\MSScript.reg"
Pause
```

The alternative way is to host the interfaces yourself in a class file. You need to implement IActiveScriptSite ay a minimum. See IActiveScript topic in VBS help http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe